# Gregorian Calendar "cal.add" Method Issues

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

I am currently attempting to write a program which returns the date 100 days from the current date of today. Here's the code:

```
public class gregorianCalendar {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int weekday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 100);
        System.out.print("100 days from today, the date will be: " + month);
        System.out.print("/" + dayOfMonth);
        System.out.println("/" + year);
    }
}
```

The output of the code gives the current date rather than the date 100 days after the current date. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where in the code is the value of `month` last modified? What value is it set to? Given the answers to those two questions, what makes you think that the output will show the correct month for the date 100 days from now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class gregorianCalendar {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 100); // <------- add should be here
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int weekday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        System.out.print("100 days from today, the date will be: " + month);
        System.out.print("/" + dayOfMonth);
        System.out.println("/" + year);
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class gregorianCalendar {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        // --------------- Current Date ------------
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int weekday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        System.out.print("today, the date is: " + month);
        System.out.print("/" + dayOfMonth);
        System.out.println("/" + year);    


        // ---------- Current date + 100------------
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 100);
        System.out.print("100 days from today, the date will be: " + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        System.out.print("/" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        System.out.println("/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    }
}
```